# How to register multiple policies in .net core using policy based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am trying to use policy based authentication using .net core . I have registered policy in start up. cs like this

```
options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21",
    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
```

Now i want to register a policy for each permission but there are hundred of permissions. How can i register all these permission dynamically OR there is any better solution.

Comment: See [Custom Authorization Policy Providers using IAuthorizationPolicyProvider in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
options
    .AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)))
    .AddPolicy("AnotherPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MaximumAgeRequirement(60)))
    ;
```

Comment: i have hundreds of policies, it will be a mess if i register them like this.